# ZF2 : How do i include the Zend_Acl component into my custom built php app?

Tags: zend-framework2, php

I'm trying to use the Zend/Permissions/Acl/Acl class into my custom built php application but I cannot get past encountering this error :

> Fatal error: Class 'Zend\Permissions\Acl\Acl' not found in /users/myuser/htdocs/test/index.php on line 9

Here is a screenshot of my file system organization and my php code I'm using. 
I copied the Acl initialization code from the documentation here : http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.permissions.acl.intro.html

[image]

I'm new to Zend framework but would really like to start using the Acl class. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`use` is not a replacement for `require`, you will need an autoloader so that the files will be included. Have a look at the [`StandardAutoloader`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.loader.standard-autoloader.html) of ZF 2.

On a separate note: it's safer to use absolute paths in the include path:

```
ini_set('include_path', ini_get('include_path') . PATH_SEPARATOR . __DIR__ . '/libraries');
```